# Exists in Facebook a similar alternative to their FB pages?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I already know that GRAPH API don't allow create FB pages. My question is: exists a similar alternative to pages (Inside FB of course) manageable by API? The idea is create a container (as the pages are) and post data to them.

Answer (score 2):

If you can store your data in text format (e.g., base64 encoded) and <2^16 characters is sufficient, you could use [Notes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/).

Depending on your needs, you'll need the following permissions `user_notes`, `friend_notes` (read access) and the extended permission/scope `create_note` to create Notes from API.

I currently can't think of another way of data storage that you can manage via API.